# Detecting Malware in the android App

Tags: malware, virus, android

I've been given an APK file, and before re-distributing to the "market" I want to make sure the given android app does not contain the malware. How can I do that ?

Business use case is similar like : I am a "market provider" or :"reseller" to which developers will submit the developed apps. To guard my reputation : I want to ensure that before I put the application in "my market", the app. is virus/malware free!

Is there any third party service, which can be used to identify if the app. contains a malware ? If not how I create this service/verification program to check the same ?

Thanks in advance.
-JE

Answer (score 4):

It depends on budget and contract with your provider how far you will be able to go. You can try and use automated scanners like [apkscan](http://apkscan.nviso.be/).

Another possibility, which will be a lot more thorough (and a lot more expensive), is to hire specialized security companies who can either perform a source code review of the application (and you will have to compile the APK yourself from the reviewed source code). If your provider does not want to give you the source code then you could request your security consultants to reverse engineer and review the provided APK. (but there might be difficulties here as well)

Comment: More Android malware analysis scanners: [Anubis: Analysis of APK](http://anubis.iseclab.org/) and [APK Analyzer](http://www.apk-analyzer.net/)

Comment: Thanks Lucas and Ivan. @Ivan : is there possibility of sending my APK using API calls instead of going to webpage and uploading it manually ?

Comment: Also you can use Yara http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/malware-analysis-clamav-yara/